# How to keep conch (shanka) after pooja (puja)?

Tags: puja

How to keep the conch (Shanka) after pooja (puja)?

1. Should it be filled with water and kept next to idol?
2. Should it be kept upside down with no water in it?

Comment: After the completion of Puja  the Shanka will be empty.With the water that was in it being poured into the Avisekha water.The Shanka is then kept flat on a stand.

Comment: 1. if the shankh is inclined towards right - called dakhinaavarti shank (in the south it is known as balamuri) & used to represent a deity & worshipped as god, it should to be keep it next to other idols. but, if it is used only to perform abhishekam it can be kept along with other pooja artiles. 2. it is not necessary to keep it upside down. this might keep it free from dust etc.